# Are there any resources for viewing or recreating SF planetarium shows?

Tags: marvel, dc, isaac-asimov

Back in the 1980s, my family had a membership at the Oregon Museum of Science and Industry.  That meant that we went to a lot of planetarium shows.  Most of the shows were purely scientific, but some had science fiction plots associated with them.  Sometimes the plots were just frame stories for the educational astronomy content, but sometimes the stories were the primary focus.

I remember two examples very clearly.  One was a planetarium version of "The Last Question," which was my first exposure to the story.  The other was part of a travelling exhibit about superheroes, and it featured a space-based plot with both Marvel and DC superheroes fighting.  (I remember thinking that would probably be the only place that I saw the Silver Surfer take on Darkseid.)  The superhero one, in particular, must have been produced elsewhere and distributed as part of the travelling exhibit.

So is there any way to find recordings or recreations of these shows somewhere online?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Planetarium version of The Last Question (as read by Leonard Nimoy) is available on Youtube. Unfortunately the images aren't available.

Comment: This is really neat.  I imagine it's the same show I saw, although I remember it slightly differently​.  It losses a lot without the slides and other projections though..